# Error while move files using shutil.move() in python

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

I am trying to move files using shut.move().....But if the file is already existing at destination ...it will raise an exception..
But I want to move the file to destination forcibly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Before moving the file to new destination, you should check if the given file is already in the destination folder. If yes, then delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shutil.copy()` which will overwrite the file.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

**EDIT**

You could first remove the file in the destination directory with `os.remove()` and then use `shutil.move()` to move the file into the destination directory.

Comment: That is correct, but it will overwrite the file in the destination directory.

Comment: @ harpal: I don't want to keep the file in Source folder...because it will be processed again...thats why i want to "Move" the file to destination.. Is there any way to do so in shut library?